# Modern Communication site, discussion board, adding rating impossible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board, modern-team-site

If you turn on the site feature of Team sites you get to have the full stack of apps, however adding a discussion board there is no 'rating settings' in the settings and even if you go there by editing the url (_layouts/RatingsSettings.aspx) it gives you an error message. Any clue why this is not permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rating is associated with Publishing infrastructure, this is why it is not present in the Communication site